# In nuxt.js (vue.js), no parameters are passed in refresh (F5)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, server-side-rendering, nuxt.js

I am using nuxt.js.

Loads data from asyncData () of page component to axios.

```
async asyncData (context) {
  const name = context.route.params.name
  const response = await axios.get ('/ users /' + name)
  return {
    user: response.data.info
  }
}
```

Navigate to  when navigating to this page and the above code will work fine.

However, if you refresh (F5) on this page component,

```
const name = context.route.params.name
```

Gets the data in name.

```
const response = await axios.get ('/ users /' + name)
```

No parameter is passed in name.

> That is, parameters are not passed to axios, and the server side does
>   not receive param values.
>
> To solve the above problem, the data was loaded from mounted () to
>   axios.

***Why does asyncData cause problems?***

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `router`! Nuxt include an helper to catch parameters.

The name of your page file must be `_name.vue`,
Then, to get the param, you can directly use `context.params.name`.

> Read the doc about dynamic routes : https://nuxtjs.org/guide/routing#dynamic-routes

---

Another point, enjoy the advantages offered by the ES6 to simplify your code ;-)

```
async asyncData ({ params }) {
  const { data } = await axios.get ('/users/' + params.name)
  return {
    user: data.info
  }
}
```

Comment: No. The meaning of name is just a variable... When importing uri params, refresh (F5) on the page will not be able to transfer that value to axios.

Comment: when you talk about "uri params" you want say "query parameters"?
https://www.rankwatch.com/learning/sites/default/files/2.jpg

Comment: I say "uri params"
": id" of "/ users /: id". There is no problem loading this value. However, there is a problem sending this value when making an axios request. This value is not passed. If you log the parameters sent from the server on the get request, a blank value is output.

Comment: The axios GET request was from asyncData () {}. That is, the results are different for asyncData () {} and mounted () {} respectively. AsyncData () fails when the page refreshes (F5), mounted () succeeds.

Comment: Which version of Nuxt ? and Node.js ?

Comment: Yes, nuxt.js -> 1.0.0-alpha.5 / node.js -> 8.1.3

Comment: Did you understand the problem I'm having?

Comment: no sorry, I don't understand :-( I did the same thing without issue: https://github.com/NicoPennec/nuxt-weather/blob/master/pages/weather/_citycode.vue#L36